Is there a way to make a subroutine argument const in winwrap?
In c++ for example you can do
void func(const int n) { /* ... */ }

Can you do a similar thing in winwrap like this?
Sub f(ByVal Const n As Long)  ' this errors
 ' ...
End Sub

